# string comparision rendered condition is not woking in glassFish 3.1

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

```
 <a4j:repeat value="#{parserForIOEditor.parsedTemplate.section}" var="section">    
 <h:dataTable id="ErrorMessages" var="sectionKey" style="width:450px;"
                     value="#{infoObjectWizardHelper.errorMessageKeys}"
                     rendered="#{func:contains(infoObjectWizardHelper.errorMessageKeys,section.name)}" >

            <h:column rendered="#{sectionKey eq section.name }" >
   //some stuff
 </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 </a4j:repeat>
```

Here my requirement is that when sectionkey equals to the section.name then only column should be displayed. could anybody give some idea on it!

**The Same code is working in glassFish 2.1 but not working in glassFish 3.1**

Comment: you sure you placed el jars in the glassFish 3.1 server ?

Comment: yes i did that. could you tell me why this kind of behaviour is being exhibited?

Comment: did you added the needed config for the el to the web.xml file ? i guess you can find those settings in the web.xml of the glassFish 2.1

Comment: yes i added all the required things and application is running perfectly other than this issue!

Comment: This problem is explainable when you would be using `<c:forEach>` instead of `<a4j:repeat>` (different tag lifecycle). To exclude the one and other, does it work if you replace `<a4j:repeat>` by `<ui:repeat>` or perhaps `<h:dataTable><h:column>`?

Comment: It is working when i used rich:dataTable instead of html:dataTable. Could anybody provide reason for this behaviour!!!